# 14.04: Cannot sign into youtube webapp

Tags: youtube, 14.04, webapps

Cannot sign into my account using the youtube webapp on Ubuntu 14.04 because everytime I click on the signin button inside the youtube's homepage on the webapp, it opens a new window of the default browser (firefox) with the google login page.

Even checking to stay signed on thisnew window and completing here the signin process, there is no consequence on the webapp where I can continue only unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

To sign in you need to change manifest.json located in `/usr/share/unity-webapps/userscripts/unity-webapps-youtube`.
Replace `{"includes":[` with `{"includes":["http:*.google.com/*","https:*.google.com/*",`.

P.S. I don't know why do you want to use webapp, but many functions in webapps since 14.04 update not gonna work.